# How to integrate safari into iphone app?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, safari

Here is a screenshot from app named [Downloads lite](http://itunes.apple.com/app/id349275540), it seems like intergrate safari into it's interface, I guess it just simulate the UI from safari. 


I'm trying to use UIWebView to display web page, but I don't know how to implement the bule progress bar background and address bar drap disabled when loading
[image: Safari interface inside app]

Answer (score 0):

[**SVWebViewController**](https://github.com/samvermette/SVWebViewController) is pretty much what you are looking for. Hope it helps...

Comment: I can't find address bar and google input field in your demo, and it should has a blue progress bar as address bar background when loading